# webrat + nokogiri + css selectors + whitespaces = Nightmare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, css-selectors, nokogiri, webrat

I need to test with Cucumber/Webrat the presence of this button:

```
<%=submit_tag 'Get it'%>
```

But when I use this custom step:

```
And I should see a button with a value of "Get it"
```

that is:

```
Then /^I should see a button with a value of "([^\"]*)"$/ do |value|
 response.should have_selector("form input[value=#{value}]")
end
```

I get:

```
    And I should see a button with a value of "Get it"                       # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:181
      unexpected ' ' after 'includesGet' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/racc/parser.rb:99:in `_racc_do_parse_c'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/racc/parser.rb:99:in `__send__'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/racc/parser.rb:99:in `do_parse'
      ./features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:182:in `/^I should see a button with a value of "([^\"]*)"$/'
```

**When I test a button with a ONE WORD value it works**, so it's the space between "Get" and "it".

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
And I should see a button named "Get it"
```

custom_steps.rb

```
Then /^I should see a button named "([^\"]*)"$/ do |name|
 response.should have_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='#{name}']")
end
```

Thanks to http://www.vermonster.com/2009/12/16/cucumber-workshop-recap/

Answer (score 0):

This appears to specifically be a problem with Nokogiri, for me:

```
page.search("input[value='Next Batch']")   # => Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError
page.search("//input[@value='Next Batch']") # => Okay
```